# Android Kotlin - convert jsonArray to Array<String>

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I get an array from an API:

```
val pics = response.getJSONArray("pics")
```

`pics` contains like:

```
["https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/19\/55\/497173801955.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/10\/34\/242830811034.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/86\/23\/808728238623.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/90\/41\/146747399041.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/47\/41\/672475854741.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/63\/94\/771076926394.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/36\/42\/182330463642.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/29\/96\/948397532996.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/82\/54\/761385508254.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/41\/42\/142837364142.jpg","https:\/\/www.bla.com\/extern\/v\/pics\/mitte\/66\/25\/215324906625.jpg"]
```

I need to get that into an `ArrayList<String>`

This is one of multiple tries after converting JAVA solutions to kotlin:

```
val list = ArrayList<String>()
for (i in 0 until pics.length()) {
   list.add(pics.getJSONObject(i).getString("name"))
}
```

And then when I try to use `list` in ViewPager then I get type mismatch:

```
Required: Array<String>

Found:kotlin.collections.ArrayList<String
```

How to do this??

Why can't it be all just simple array() like in PHP smh this is all beyond annoying

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`Array<String>` and `ArrayList<String>` are 2 different types.

What you need to provide is `Array<String>` but what you are actually providing is `ArrayList<String>`.

```
val list = Array(pics.length()) {
    pics.getString(it)
}
```

Comment: Answer doesn't help if you've got an actual JSONArray and want to convert to an Array<String>

Comment: @Justin could you please elaborate, JSONArray implements `length()` from `List` and has `getString(int)` method to retrieve a String element at nth position, how isn't this working for you?

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I've actually got this working now. I was just commenting on the fact that it wasn't working for me, using the json library. I ended up using the iterator and looping through and copying to an array.